# performance tuning for JSF

Tags: java, optimization, jsf, performance

Can any one list out the tips to tune JSF WebApp @ its best.

Comment: Depends strongly on where your bottlenecks are.

Comment: This is very general question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JSF RichFace](http://www.javaplex.com/blog/optimizing-jsf-richfaces-applications/)

> Never put logic into your getters.
>   They are called multiple times and
>   should only return something already
>   populated by another method. For
>   example if you are chaining drop-downs
>   together use an a4j:support tag on the
>   first one with an action attribute
>   that loads the data which is then
>   retrieved when you reRender the second
>   one.
>
> Use the ajaxSingle="true" unless
>   you actually want to send the whole
>   form back to the server.
>   Don't use a
>   rich component if you only need a
>   normal one. For example don't use
>   rich:dataTable unless you are making
>   use of some of the features that it
>   has over and above h:dataTable.
>
> Consider using immediate=true
>   attributes on elements where you do
>   not need validation Avoid displaying
>   large tables to user.
>
> Use pagination
>   Do not over complicate EL expressions,
>   code them in Java in backing bean

[JSF BestPractices](http://webmoli.com/2008/05/20/jsf-best-practices/)
[Performance Tuning](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Comment: Some of the comments in JSF BestPractices are old. for example the usage of c:if - it's not recommended to use JSTL in JSF. it also breaks some functionality like ViewScope in JSF2

Comment: More I am expecting from BalusC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628570/jsf-tuning this also seems a relevant discussion

Answer (score 1):

Moving to *Stateless* JSF would offer a great performance boost.  Now it's possible to use JSF entirely stateless. See [this blog](http://industrieit.com/blog/2011/11/stateless-jsf-high-performance-zero-per-request-memory-overhead/) & [this issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1055). A payoff is that you can't create views dynamically (e.g. by binding, JSTL tags, etc), nor manipulate it after creation.

---

> A Stateless JSF operation mode
>   would be incredibly useful for high-load applications and
>   architectures:
>
> http://industrieit.com/blog/2011/11/stateless-jsf-high-performance-zero-per-request-memory-overhead/#comment-4
>
> This has previously been suggested by Jacob:
>   http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jhook/archive/2006/01/experiment_goin.html
>
> This would help JSF ditch the stigma of "slow and memory hog," and
>   help keep up with current tech trends (stateless architectures.)

Comment: Is JSF really required in that case ?

Comment: stateless JSF is just an extension to mojarra implementation of JSF. So your pages would load superfast as the view is not rebuit/modified everytime, & you also say goodbye to those stale views(incase you used  server state saving mode) while you enjoy all the other advantages of fast & easy development with JSF. Checkout the link for details